# How to insert an image into a FlipView of a list?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a GridView with image, to tap on any of them, you open a FlipView with images of GridView can watch with the swipe. I wish I could do the tapping on an image of the grid and bring up the control FlipView already with that image previously selected, and does not begin to always display the first image of the list. how can I do?

This is XAML code:

```
<FlipView x:Name="FlipBig" Visibility="Collapsed" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVSOpere}}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="295" Height="340">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
              <Grid>
                 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <RowDefinition Height="290"/>
                       <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Gray">
                    <Image Source="{Binding URLOpera}" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" Margin="3,3,3,3" Grid.Row="0" />
                  </Border>
                  <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomeOpera}"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>  
                  </Border>
               </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

this is my class in c#:

```
namespace App1
{
    class MuseoOpera
    {
        public string NomeMuseoContenuta { get; set; }
        public string NomeOpera { get; set; }
        public string URLOpera { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the SelectedIndex of the FlipView

Answer (score 0):

The usercontrols are considered derived types, and do not inherit styles implicitly.

One thing you can do is set the style on the UserControl initialization

```
Style = (Style)FindResource(typeof (UserControl));
```